# Authorize.net CIM Duplicate Transaction Window

Tags: php, payment-gateway, credit-card, authorize.net, payment-processing

I'm working with Authorize.net's Customer Information Manager API (CIM). My test case is centered around a user giving the wrong address during checkout.

My application will attempt to create a customer profile each time the user submits the form:

```
$txrq = new AuthorizeNetCIM;
$txrsp = $txrq->createCustomerProfileTransaction("AuthCapture", $transaction, 'x_duplicate_window=0');
```

I've tried setting passing `x_duplicate_window` as you can see above to "Extra Options," which, in the SDK, is the following part of the request:

```
<extraOptions><![CDATA[' . $this->_extraOptions . ']]></extraOptions>
```

No matter what value I use for x_duplicate_window, authorize.net will always return an error until the default time has passed.

```
AuthorizeNet Error: Response Code: 3 Response Subcode: 1 Response Reason Code: 11 Response Reason Text: A duplicate transaction has been submitted.
```

I worry if one of our (potential) users tries to submit the wrong address, realizes his or her error, and then gets greeted with 3 more additional minutes of errors while the transaction timeout occurs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an error in the Authorize.net SDK code:

~Line 360-364 in `CIM.php's method _setPostString()`

```
if ($this->_extraOptions) {
    $this->_xml->addChild("extraOptions");
    $this->_post_string = str_replace("<extraOptions></extraOptions>",'<extraOptions><![CDATA[' . $this->_extraOptions . ']]></extraOptions>', $this->_xml->asXML());
    $this->_extraOptions = false;
}
```

`$this->_xml->addChild("extraOptions");` results in a node that does not match the str_replace call: `<extraOptions/>`

Modifying the str_replace will remedy this, which will pass along the **x_duplicate_window** parameter just fine:

```
if ($this->_extraOptions) {
    $this->_xml->addChild("extraOptions");
    $this->_post_string = str_replace("<extraOptions/>",'<extraOptions><![CDATA[' . $this->_extraOptions . ']]></extraOptions>', $this->_xml->asXML());
    $this->_extraOptions = false;
}
```

Comment: Authorize.net's API is terrible, I'm having a miserable experience working with it.

Comment: I have to say, Stripe has been the best payment processing API I've ever used.